# Toggle Javascript outside of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have issues when trying to place an event to toggle a `div` using an element outside of the parent container.

I trying to target the same behavior from outside of the parent elements using a `span` tag.

Any help would be grateful.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='toggle_parent'>
    <div class='toggleHolder'>
      <span class='toggler'>Open</span> 
      <span class='toggler' style='display:none;'>Close</span>
    </div>

    <div class='toggled_content' style='display:none;width:100%;height:400px;'>
        <h2>Hello This Is My Content Right Here</h2>
        <span class='toggler btn btn-large'>Close</span>      
    </div>
</div>



 <!-- I need this element to trigger from outside -->
 <span class="toggler btn btn-large btn-info">Gain Early Access</span>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.toggler').live('click',function(){
/*   $(this).parent().children().toggle();  //swaps the display:none between the two spans */
$(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content').slideToggle();  //swap the display of the main content with slide action

});
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `$('.toggled_content').slideToggle()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amended your example to suit the purpose.

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <div>
          <span class='open'>Open</span> 
          <span class='close' style='display:none;'>Close</span>
        </div>

        <div class='content' style='display:none;width:100%;height:400px;'>
            <h2>Hello This Is My Content Right Here</h2>
            <span class='close'>Close</span>      
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- I need this element to trigger from outside -->
    <span class="toggle">Gain Early Access</span>
</div>

$(".toggle").click( function( ) {
    $(".content").slideToggle();
});
$(".open").click( function( ) {
    $(".content").slideDown();
});
$(".close").click( function( ) {
    $(".content").slideUp();
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hc3je/10/ - this is exaclty what I want but for some weird reason it doesnt work off of my computer or server!? im using jquery 1.8.2 min version

Comment: Are you getting any errors on your server if you go into your browser's developer tools?

Comment: got it, for some reason the 1.8.2 version of jquery I had did not support easing. - thanks this work great

Answer (score 0):

Just use a global parent div.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class='toggle_parent'>
        <div class='toggleHolder'>
          <span class='toggler'>Open</span> 
          <span class='toggler' style='display:none;'>Close</span>
        </div>

        <div class='toggled_content' style='display:none;width:100%;height:400px;'>
            <h2>Hello This Is My Content Right Here</h2>
            <span class='toggler btn btn-large'>Close</span>      
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- I need this element to trigger from outside -->
    <span class="toggler btn btn-large btn-info">Gain Early Access</span>
</div>
```

And you can just do this :

```
var container = $('#container');
container.on('click', '.toggler', function() {
    container.find('.toggleHolder .toggler').toggle();
    container.find('.toggle_content').slideToggle();
});
```

By the way, if you use jQuery 1.7 or more, `live` is deprecated. See http://api.jquery.com/live/